# Привязка блока с помощью "float" - "ломает" код

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, проблема с позиционированием блока.
В блоке находятся 2 дочерних блока, один из которых должен находится слева, другой справа.

Пытаюсь поставить второй блок (колесо на изображении) с помощью `float: right;`. Все хорошо, он становится точно куда я хотел его запихнуть.

Но вот в чем проблема, при уменьшении размера экрана, он выходит за родительский блок, будто он не учитывает его размеры и не увеличивается под него.

1. Без `float: right;`
2. C `float: right;`
3. Нормальный размер экрана `float: right;`

[image: Без float: right;]
[image: C float: right;][image: Нормальный размер экрана float: right;]

Comment: задайте `overflow:hidden` родительскому блоку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"overflow:hidden" - решил проблему.

Спасибо за помощь Геннадию Журову!